# Why is the Kotlin Synthetic is Null unless I use an explicit scope

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

So I have a bit of code here that used to work 1 month ago.

```
profile_clickable.throttleClicks {
  logger.logEvent(PageTags.MENU_PROFILE_NAV)
  edit_picture_button.visibility = View.GONE
  ProfileActivity.start(this@HomeMenuActivity, avatar.transition(), username.transition())
}
```

This code now fails with an NPE on `edit_picture_button`, `avatar`, and `username` which are all Kotlin synthetics.

When I add an explicit call to each of those items (see below) suddenly it works.

```
profile_clickable.throttleClicks {
  logger.logEvent(PageTags.MENU_PROFILE_NAV)
  this@HomeMenuActivity.edit_picture_button.visibility = View.GONE
  ProfileActivity.start(this@HomeMenuActivity, this@HomeMenuActivity.avatar.transition(), this@HomeMenuActivity.username.transition())
}
```

throttleClicks is an extension method that does this:

```
fun View.throttleClicks(
  windowDurationMs: Long = 800,
  onClick: View.() -> Unit
) {
  setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {

    // Set lastClickTime to - windowDurationMs to ensure the first click won't be throttled.
    var lastClickTime = -windowDurationMs

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
      val time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
      if (time - lastClickTime >= windowDurationMs) {
        lastClickTime = time
        onClick()
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Why do I suddenly have to use an explicit scope to avoid NPEs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use synthetics in functiun of type `View.() -> Unit`.

So `this` in function is view on whitch you apply this function (`profile_clickable`).

Kotlin synthetics works like

```
val View.profile_clickable: ImageView get() {
  if (cache exists) {
    return cache
  }
  return this.findViewById(R.id.profile_clickable)
}
```

`profile_clickable` hasn't any childs, so there will be exception.

You can use this code:

```
profile_clickable.throttleClicks {
  logger.logEvent(PageTags.MENU_PROFILE_NAV)
  this@HomeMenuActivity.run {
    edit_picture_button.visibility = View.GONE
    ProfileActivity.start(this, avatar.transition(), username.transition())
  }
}
```

Comment: Your right,  it looks like the throttleClicks method was changed from an RXjava version to a non RX version. thank you!